# puttext on bottom left

Tags: android, opencv

Im using the following code to write text on rectangle.

```
public static void drawRectangleAndLabelOnPreview(Mat img, Rect face, String label) {

        Imgproc.putText(img, label, face.tl(), Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, FONT_SIZE, FACE_RECT_COLOR, FONT_THICKNESS);
    }
```

I want the rectangle on bottom but it is still in the top. How can I be able to put it in bottom left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Rect` face coordinates to bottom left position where you want to put text in the image.

Suppose w and h are width and height of your text box and r and c are number of rows and columns in the image respectively. Then, set face x, y values as:

```
face.x = 0;
face.y = r - h - 1;
```

These values are for example if you want to set box on bottom left position. You can change if you want to change position.

Comment: thank you Jazz... is it possible to use custom fonts in opencv android?

Comment: You can use one of the following types as font in OpenCV PutText: FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, or FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, where each of the font ID’s can be combined with FONT_ITALIC to get the slanted letters.